# How to get 3 latest voted user from Amity SDK?

Tags: sdk

I just used Amity social SDK to create a poll post but unfortunately I can't find a way to get users who voted on my poll. Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Android SDK does not return list of users who voted on a poll post but you can use [amity-api](https://api.sg.amity.co/api/v3/polls/pollID/answers/answerID) as a workaround. This API will return a list of users who voted.

Comment: Going forward, please edit your first answer instead of deleting it and posting a new one.